# Lazy Load images on Listview in android(Beginner Level)?

Tags: android, listview, android-lazyadapter, android-lazyloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - How do I do a lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

I am working on the listview with the custom adapter. I want to load the images  and text view on it. The images are load from the internet urls. I just want to show the images which are visible list item to hte user. I refered the [Shelves opensource project example from romainguy](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/activity/BooksAdapter.java), but its to complicated to understand the code. For a beginner level, I just want to know how to handle the tag between the adapter and activity. From the [commonsware](http://www.androidguys.com/2008/07/22/fancy-listviews-part-three/) [example](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-thumbnail/tree) I can set the tag on adapter, but can't show the corresponding image at the idle state of the listview. Please help me with your ideas. Sample codes are more understandable.

Thanks.

EDIT:

The combination of [Efficient](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html) and [Slow](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List13.html) Adapter in ApiDemos is more helpful to understand.

changes done on efficient adapter example like this:

```
public class List14 extends ListActivity implements ListView.OnScrollListener {
// private TextView mStatus;

private static boolean mBusy = false;
static ViewHolder holder;

public static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Bitmap mIcon1;
    private Bitmap mIcon2;

    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Icons bound to the rows.
        mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.icon48x48_1);
        mIcon2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.icon48x48_2);
    }

    /**
     * The number of items in the list is determined by the number of
     * speeches in our array.
     * 
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getCount()
     */
    public int getCount() {
        return DATA.length;
    }

    /**
     * Since the data comes from an array, just returning the index is
     * sufficent to get at the data. If we were using a more complex data
     * structure, we would return whatever object represents one row in the
     * list.
     * 
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItem(int)
     */
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * Use the array index as a unique id.
     * 
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItemId(int)
     */
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * Make a view to hold each row.
     * 
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
     *      android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid
        // unneccessary calls
        // to findViewById() on each row.

        // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is
        // no need
        // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView
        // supplied
        // by ListView is null.
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_text,
                    null);

            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children
            // views
            // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if (!mBusy) {
            holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);

            // Null tag means the view has the correct data
            holder.icon.setTag(null);
        } else {
            holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mIcon2);

            // Non-null tag means the view still needs to load it's data
            holder.icon.setTag(this);
        }
        holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);

        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
        // holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        ImageView icon;
    }
}

private Bitmap mIcon1;
private Bitmap mIcon2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
            R.drawable.icon48x48_1);
    mIcon2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
            R.drawable.icon48x48_2);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
}

public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
}

public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    switch (scrollState) {
    case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
        mBusy = false;

        int first = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int count = view.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            holder.icon = (ImageView) view.getChildAt(i).findViewById(
                    R.id.icon);
            if (holder.icon.getTag() != null) {
                holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
                holder.icon.setTag(null);
            } 
        }

        // mStatus.setText("Idle");
        break;
    case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL:
        mBusy = true;
        // mStatus.setText("Touch scroll");
        break;
    case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING:
        mBusy = true;
        // mStatus.setText("Fling");
        break;
    }
}
private static final String[] DATA = { "Abbaye de Belloc",
        "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
        "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu"};
}
```

It works fine now. But when the scrolling state its not reloading the image properly. some interval of items not shows the images2. that is the correct order of the images are loading. But not in all items of list. Mismatches happening between solid item intervals. 
how to correct it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Praveen -

As you already found my blog post on this, I just wanted to push it back to Stackoverflow so that others can use it.

Here's the basic discussion:
http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/loading-remote-images-in-a-listview-on-android/

And there's a class I documented later that uses a thread and a callback to load the images:

http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/loading-images-over-http-on-a-separate-thread-on-android/

**Update:** To address your specific exception, I think that view returned in the list from `getChildAt` is not an `ImageView` -- it's whatever layout view you are using to hold the image and text.

**Update to include relevant code**: (Per @george-stocker's recommendation)

Here is the adapter I was using:

```
public class MediaItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MediaItem> {
  private final static String TAG = "MediaItemAdapter";
  private int resourceId = 0;
  private LayoutInflater inflater;
  private Context context;

  private ImageThreadLoader imageLoader = new ImageThreadLoader();

  public MediaItemAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<MediaItem> mediaItems) {
    super(context, 0, mediaItems);
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view;
    TextView textTitle;
    TextView textTimer;
    final ImageView image;

    view = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

    try {
      textTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text);
      image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    } catch( ClassCastException e ) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Your layout must provide an image and a text view with ID's icon and text.", e);
      throw e;
    }

    MediaItem item = getItem(position);
    Bitmap cachedImage = null;
    try {
      cachedImage = imageLoader.loadImage(item.thumbnail, new ImageLoadedListener() {
      public void imageLoaded(Bitmap imageBitmap) {
      image.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
      notifyDataSetChanged();                }
      });
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Bad remote image URL: " + item.thumbnail, e);
    }

    textTitle.setText(item.name);

    if( cachedImage != null ) {
      image.setImageBitmap(cachedImage);
    }

    return view;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

I got it. This is the perfect code I want. Lazy loading works to custom adapter just visible list item's icons. Hope it helps to the beginners

```
public class List14 extends ListActivity implements ListView.OnScrollListener {
// private TextView mStatus;

private static boolean mBusy = false;
static ViewHolder holder;

public static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Bitmap mIcon1;
    private Bitmap mIcon2;
    private Context mContext;

    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mContext = context;
        // Icons bound to the rows.
        mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.icon48x48_1);
        mIcon2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.icon48x48_2);
    }

    /**
     * The number of items in the list is determined by the number of
     * speeches in our array.
     * 
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getCount()
     */
    public int getCount() {
        return DATA.length;
    }

    /**
     * Since the data comes from an array, just returning the index is
     * sufficent to get at the data. If we were using a more complex data
     * structure, we would return whatever object represents one row in the
     * list.
     * 
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItem(int)
     */
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * Use the array index as a unique id.
     * 
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItemId(int)
     */
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * Make a view to hold each row.
     * 
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
     *      android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid
        // unneccessary calls
        // to findViewById() on each row.

        // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is
        // no need
        // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView
        // supplied
        // by ListView is null.
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_text,
                    parent, false);

            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children
            // views
            // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

             convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (!mBusy) {

            holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);

            // Null tag means the view has the correct data
            holder.icon.setTag(null);

        } else {
            holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mIcon2);

            // Non-null tag means the view still needs to load it's data
            holder.icon.setTag(this);
        }
        holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);

        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
        // holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        ImageView icon;
    }
}

private Bitmap mIcon1;
private Bitmap mIcon2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
            R.drawable.icon48x48_1);
    mIcon2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
            R.drawable.icon48x48_2);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
}

public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
}

public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    switch (scrollState) {
    case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
        mBusy = false;

        int first = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int count = view.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            holder.icon = (ImageView) view.getChildAt(i).findViewById(
                    R.id.icon);
            if (holder.icon.getTag() != null) {
                holder.icon.setImageBitmap(IMAGE[first+i]);// this is the image url array.
                holder.icon.setTag(null);
            }
        }

        // mStatus.setText("Idle");
        break;
    case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL:
        mBusy = true;
        // mStatus.setText("Touch scroll");
        break;
    case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING:
        mBusy = true;
        // mStatus.setText("Fling");
        break;
    }
}

private static final String[] DATA = { "Abbaye de Belloc",
        "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
        "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu",
        "Yarra Valley Pyramid", "Yorkshire Blue", "Zamorano",
        "Zanetti Grana Padano", "Zanetti Parmigiano Reggiano" };
  }
```

Comment: it is a bit strange that you use a holder and then always use findViewById ... you could make it simple if you avoid that holder thing or faster if you set the things with the help of the holder ...

Answer (score 8):

As far as I understand you need to update your list after scrolling is finished. That's easy. Here's the fixed code for you:

```
EfficientAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
            R.drawable.icon48x48_1);
    mIcon2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
            R.drawable.icon48x48_2);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adapter=new EfficientAdapter(this);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
}

public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
}

public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    switch (scrollState) {
    case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
        mBusy = false;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() 
        break;
    case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL:
        mBusy = true;
        // mStatus.setText("Touch scroll");
        break;
    case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING:
        mBusy = true;
        // mStatus.setText("Fling");
        break;
    }
}
```

notifyDataSetChanged will tell the adapter to re-display all visible items, so they'll be displayed with image2.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the static `ViewHolder` isn't helping anything. Try putting the entire `onScrollStateChanged` function between `/*` and `*/`, removing the `static ViewHolder` line, and changing `holder = new ViewHolder();` to `ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();`.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, check your logcat to make sure your app isn't being killed and restarted.  Most handsets limit your total application size to 16mb or 24mb.   It's easy to load up a bunch of images, run over, get killed, restart, and have your onPause not load big data off screen.   It's poor man's garabage collection.