# something similar to SDWebImage in iOS for Android?

Tags: android, ios

I was looking for something similar to SDWebImage for Android. What SDWebImage does in iOS is this:

load images from URL, uses cache, does asynchronous downloading.

I am looking for something similar for Android. Any hint ?

Thanks.

Comment: something similar :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912054/lazy-load-images-on-listview-in-androidbeginner-level

Answer (score 8):

Something simple that I'm using for a project is called Picasso:

https://github.com/square/picasso

I use SDWebImage in my iOS side of the project and Picasso is just as easy.

Answer (score 3):

At Applidium, we recently ported SDWebImage to Android. It's called Shutterbug, and it does everything you asked for.

Here is a link to the project: https://github.com/applidium/Shutterbug. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I Got this answer in following link : [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

```
   package com.wilson.android.library;
```

/*
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
*/

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class DrawableManager {
private final Map<String, Drawable> drawableMap;

public DrawableManager() {
    drawableMap = new HashMap<String, Drawable>();
}

public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) {
    if (drawableMap.containsKey(urlString)) {
        return drawableMap.get(urlString);
    }

    Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "image url:" + urlString);
    try {
        InputStream is = fetch(urlString);
        Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");


        if (drawable != null) {
            drawableMap.put(urlString, drawable);
            Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "got a thumbnail drawable: " + drawable.getBounds() + ", "
                    + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() + "," + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() + ", "
                    + drawable.getMinimumHeight() + "," + drawable.getMinimumWidth());
        } else {
          Log.w(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "could not get thumbnail");
        }

        return drawable;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "fetchDrawable failed", e);
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "fetchDrawable failed", e);
        return null;
    }
}

public void fetchDrawableOnThread(final String urlString, final ImageView imageView) {
    if (drawableMap.containsKey(urlString)) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawableMap.get(urlString));
    }

    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            imageView.setImageDrawable((Drawable) message.obj);
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO : set imageView to a "pending" image
            Drawable drawable = fetchDrawable(urlString);
            Message message = handler.obtainMessage(1, drawable);
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}

private InputStream fetch(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    return response.getEntity().getContent();
}
```

}

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

A simple library to display images in Android. Images are being downloaded asynchronously in the background. Images are being cached on SD card and in memory. Can also be used for GridView and just to display images into an ImageView.

Something to keep in mind, this will create a folder on the SD card called LazyList, but since it is open source you can change the name easily. This was built with lists in mind, however you can just as easily use it anywhere.