# List view with image and two item?

Tags: android, listview, addition

Hi i am trying to show two item in list view.i know we can do this with the following.  `ArrayList<Map<String, String>>`  but i need to show one image along with this two item.
Here is a image which I want.

[image]

I create xml file with one imageview and two text view.i don't understand how to do this.

Comment: check http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ how it works fine?

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2012/02/24/android-tutorialndashadding-images-to-your-custom-multi-line-listview.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement the class `ArrayAdapter` and create your own `ListAdapter`.

See: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Layout file with your cell design. In the Adapter, then you get a View from the Layout programmatically calling the current layout inflate method, and fill the fields and return it.

Comment: Hi Sandip, You should create custom ListView to display images and text together. To display images, you require Lazy Loading.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a implementation of such a list: [Contact-Picture-Sync](https://github.com/heinrisch/Contact-Picture-Sync)

Answer (score 1):

For me the way to do it is using BaseAdapter. You need to have the list view on the activity, one xml for the item layout and then on the listview call the setAdapter() with the adapter.

You can find some info here: 
[Lazy Load images on Listview in android(Beginner Level)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912054/lazy-load-images-on-listview-in-androidbeginner-level)

Answer (score 1):

firt of all you should use an ArrayList with an own object like

```
Class MyListeItem {

    String text1;
    String text2;
    String image;
}

List<MyListItem> = new ArrayList<MyListItem>();
```

then create create a class extending BaseAdapter which holds the list.
create an xml-file ie. "my_listitem" in the res/layouts folder and in the getView() method of the BaseAdapter do something like

```
LinearLayout layout =  (LinearLayout)View.inflate(context, R.layout.my_listitem, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a `list item` xml layout file you can use with the `simplest attributes`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_date_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tomorrow"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_high_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="25°"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_low_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6°"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this will appear like this

[image]

and you `can remove` the last nested `LinearLayout` to match your requirement

and here are the `invisible boundaries`
[image]