# Android UI design?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

To be very honest, I am very new to android development. I really want to learn it.
I'm facing problem in UI design. I want to make something like the picture given below.

[image: Android Interface I'm trying to acheive]

Now my question is the that the list of person is dynamic (received from a web service). Now how can I achieve that.

I'm guessing I have to make a XML layout of one and then load it in the layout using code?

i've done something as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html).. but that is not enough. :(
Please help!

**** EDIT ****
I want this

[image]

to be dynamic. I have successfully created the above image strip in a separate XML.
now can it be used in the main layout dynamically like we used to do in case of User Controls in .NET?

Comment: I can create the ui for you if you provide the icons used here

Comment: Thanks mate. But will that be dynamic (based on the data webservice returns). for example if the webservice returns "3", then 3 strips gets loaded and so on?

Comment: Yes of-course, this is what list-view is used for. If you need a dynamic list, where list contents will change dynamically, then you should use a listview.

Comment: here are the icons, http://www.mediafire.com/?qg7as2v8wz4sr14 please explain me also. Thanks.

Comment: Put this as your answer. :) Btw, I'm studying Customized ListView in greater detail so that it's easy for me to understand. Thanks a ton again.

Comment: Working on it, need some time.

Comment: -1 this question shows no attempt to research or do your own work.  This question should have been closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.mediafire.com/?zaa7gbb8jl96z41) is the project file. For simplicity I used a SimpleAdapter. You can create your custom adapter to meet your requirements. Hope you like this ui...  :)

Comment: -1 While I'm sure this answer helps the OP it is susceptible to [linkrot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) and makes no explanation here on SO, therefore unlikely to help future users.  Please avoid "coding for free".

Answer (score 5):

You have to work with ListViews. Just watch the [Google I/O ListView video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) for a good introduction. The actual layout of cells will be done in a separate layout XML file.

Answer (score 2):

here is important for you..following link provide how to adjust image along with two item. 
[refere this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152871/list-view-with-image-and-two-item)

Comment: thanks a lot for the link. But that link solves only halfway of my problem which I have already done. I need to replicate the UI (in that post) dynamically based on a webservice's callback. I cannot use the XML <include/> tag as i need this to be from the code (dynamic). :(

Comment: -1 this could be posted as a comment, doesn't warrant an answer.