# Android Memory Managment

Tags: android, caching, memory-management

An applications performance depends on how the memory is being managed. As we do have limited memory on the android devices, then it becomes very essential to manage memory in a efficient manner.

I am building an application which has several images kept on the server. I need to show them in a list fashion. I am fetching images from server onto my sdcard and then displaying them in the list.
But during this whole process i am get delay in the list display. It seems i am not able to manage memory properly.

Please suggest efficient memory management techniques.

Comment: Seems to me that the images are large. Perhaps you should create a thumbnail for each one? Also, fetching should happen on a non-UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

It is done through lazy loading in android and you should use onscrolllistener read this link
[Lazy Load images on Listview in android(Beginner Level)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912054/lazy-load-images-on-listview-in-androidbeginner-level) and also http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-thumbnail