# Making an android app with 365 imageviews

Tags: android, database, memory, bitmap, imageview

I need help understanding how I would approach making an Android application that allows the user to scroll through 365 different bitmaps. I'm worried that I will go outside of the memory limits that android allows. I've tried googling, but haven't been able to understand how to approach the problem. Could someone write a very brief hint at where i can start researching this?

Comment: reuse the imageviews when they scroll outta screen

Comment: Is this in a ListView or a Gallery?

Comment: Are those bitmaps stored in your apk or you have to retrieve them from the internets?

Answer (score 0):

It depens on the source of those. I think you would like to use "lazy load ListView".
[Checkout this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912054/lazy-load-images-on-listview-in-androidbeginner-level)

Answer (score 0):

how about using any class that extends from AdapterView (like listView, gridView,...) ?

the idea is that since the user doesn't really see all of the views at the same time , you can re-use views that are being disappeared when scrolling , and show them as new ones .

watch the video of google called "[the world of listView](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html)" .

anyway , if you don't wish to use this solution , consider being very "cheap" on the memory , as you are correct - android will kill your app if you use too much RAM .

you can read about handling bitmaps [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) .